# Access SQL: order by customized cases and pivot by month

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, sql-order-by, pivot

I wrote a crosstab "A" in Access which selects 2 text columns and 2 number columns, month and posts from another table "B".

An excerpt of the code is like this...

```
Select B.xx...
From B
Group by B.xx...
Pivot B.Month;
```

...which works fine if the months belong to the same year, but since the months are on a rolling basis, when the year carries over, for e.g. month are {October, November, December, January, February}, the order just stays as B.Month ASC **{01, 02, 10, 11, 12}** and I want it to be pivoted in order like **{10 11 12 01 02}**

UPDATE: I fixed the main problem, but now I want to 
1. change the order to 10/2013 to 3/2014
2. change the headings to 10 to 3

```
TOPIC        SUB-TOPIC   1/2014   10/2013   11/2013   12/2013   2/2014  3/2014
language     english      86        88         90       82        88      90
language     french       70        77         75       79        82      80
mathematics  geometry     xx        xx         xx       xx        xx      xx 
mathematics  calculus     xx        xx         xx       xx        xx      xx
```

Comment: Not that it was going to solve the problem but Access doesn't support the `case/when` syntax

Comment: why are year and month in two columns? were the previously one column?

Comment: @Brad there is only the month column in A and B, I tried adding the Year by passing it in but that didn't work cuz the pivot only works on month

Comment: But how do you get month an year? Is there a column with a proper `date/time` data type?

Comment: @Brad Yes in another table, say D, which contains all the raw data. where I've extracted month(date_column) out to be used for the final table A. And I tried to extract year(date_column) but in the end the pivot can only pivot one column...

Comment: You should leave your raw value in and only change it at the last possible moment or at least do something like `dateserial(year(now),month(now),1)` so you still have a full datetime data type

Comment: @Brad In that case, does Access allow me to Pivot (Year(now), Month(now)) or something like that?

Comment: you have to use the full function. It will pivot on it because it is one value.

Comment: And don't use `Now`, use whatever your column name is. `now` is just for example. You can execute that in an immediate window and see what it does as an example

Comment: @Brad I tried to incorporate the full date in my steps and that changes my selected data

Comment: previously did you have data like `Nov 1, 2012` and `Nov 1, 2012`? By just grouping my Month you are merging years. Which produced the right result?

Comment: @Brad I have data like "02/10/2013" and before i used month(date_column) and year(date_column) separately but not sure how to combine them in to be 10/2013.

Comment: The question is do you have the same month from more than one year in your query?

Comment: @Brad Nope I only have data for 5 months per query run, so right now I only have Nov 2013 - Mar 2014, but i do have numerous entries of the same date, etc 02/11/2013, each with a different topic. My query is to combine all the posts by specific topics under the same month, then in the end pivot the topics by month to have an aggregated chart.

Comment: you should post some sample data and your code so we can replicate the problem here. Too hard guessing.

Comment: @Brad yeup i updated!

Comment: As long as you have the month first then the year, you'll get the wrong sort order.  Put the year 1st and then the month and it will work.

Comment: @DonGeorge you are very right, now I have them in the same order, just that name is 2014/3 instead of Mar, do you know how to fix that without adding more dummy tables? Monthname(Month, true) has an error..

Comment: Since the sort order is controlled by the column heading, I think you are stuck with what you have - if you change it to a month name, the sort order will change again.  And you may want to change the month part to 2 digits, ie 2014/03, to  make sure you get what you expect once you add October to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Create an expression that includes both the year and the month, and use it in the pivot.

something like  `Pivot (year & format(month,"00"))`

or, if you have the complete date in a field, something like  `Pivot Format (Date,"yyyy/mm/dd")

as a reminder, Year, Date and Month may be reserved words and you may need different field names - not sure, but likely

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but if I pivot both the year and month, what will show up as the column name for the column?  Does "Pivot (year & format(month, '00") As Monthnum work? And no I only have the month part pulled in from the general data since that's the only thing needed.  And yes, month and year are reserved.

Comment: I think what you suggested should work - the As Monthnum shouldn't change anything.  As to what you'll get - columns should look something like 201309 .. 201310 .. 201311 .. 201312 .. 201401 .. 201402 and so on - try it and see what you get, and apply any formatting you like as long as the year comes first followed by the month.